# How to use map() and reduce() functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nosql, mapreduce

I am writting a simple function that would allow me to calculate prime numbers on one of nosql databases. After multiple approaches, i got an error that value i am looking for is not defined, thus I would appreciate your feedback.

Here is what i have tried:

1. First I have generated a set of numbers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) db.exemplary.insert( {x: Math.random()} );
```

2.Secondly I have defined map function

```
map = function() {
    for (var i = 2; i < x; i++){
        if(x % i == 0)
            try {} catch (e) {};
    }
        emit(i, value);
  };
```

3. In the end the reduce function:

```
reduce = function (i,value){return array.sum(value)}
```

4. I assigned the collection to variable and called the function:

```
collection = db.exemplary
var result = collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}});
```

As per my begginer understanding the *map* step should check whether the number is prime or not.
*Reduce* step on the other hand should sum all occurrences of prime numbers.
I got error that *x* is not defined, but it is present in the db.exemplary collection.

I would appreciate every improvement hint/suggestion for above functionality.

EDIT: Currently my function does not "emit" any results of map operation, working on this bit now.

Comment: You're getting the error because your map function uses x although it wasn't defined. You probably want to pass it to the function: `map = function(x) {`

Comment: Thank you, after introducing the change ,error does not occur anymore. Function does not produce any results though

Comment: Is there any chance you can put a [mre] in the question?

Comment: Thank you for that comment, i have added missing steps to point 4

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() generates by default float numbers from 0 to <1.
then in your generator you should use a function like this, for example to get random numbers from 0 to 999 :

```
{ x: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) }
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, mixing those two gave me right numbers